# Best way to calculate a non-broken streak of days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my app a User has_many Gestures. What is a good way to calculate how many subsequent days the User has done Gestures?

Right now I'm doing it like below, and it works as I want it to. But clearly it doesn't scale.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...

  def calculate_current_streak
    return 0 unless yesterday = gestures.done_on_day(Date.today-1)
    i = 0
    while gesture = self.gestures.done_on_day(Date.today - (i+1).days).first
      i += 1
    end
    i += 1 if gestures.done_on_day(Date.today).first
    i
  end

end
```

Thanks! Special points to the one who can work in a way to only track business days too :)

Comment: Can you explain the db table structure - do you have a gestures table with a record and timestamp for each gesture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it this way:

The length of the streak is equivalent to the number of (business) days passed since the last (business) day the user didn't use gestures at all, right?

So the solution boils down to calculating most recent day that the user didn't make a gesture.

In order to do this most easily, there's a trick that lots of DB admins use: they create DB table with *all* dates (say, all the dates from year 2000 to year 2100). The table needs to have only date field, but you can throw in a Boolean field to mark non-working days, such as weekends and holidays. Such table can be handy in *lots* of queries, and you only have to create and fill it once. ([Here's](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) a more detailed article on such tables, written for MS SQL, but insightful anyway.)

Having this table (let's call it `dates`), you can calculate your pre-streak date using something like (pseudo-SQL):

```
SELECT d.date
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN gestures g ON d.date = g.date AND g.user_id = <put_user_id_here>
WHERE d.date < TODAY() AND g.date IS NULL AND d.work_day = TRUE
ORDER BY d.date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Interesting trick. Not sure if it's better than manipulating a calendar object in memory but it is easier.